# How can I write apps with Java for Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: application-development, java, ubuntu-touch

How can I write apps with Java for Ubuntu Phone?
I am waiting this operating system and I want to be the one of those that
will write apps for this new operating system.
Best regards.
Nodar